# OCaml, how do i alter an element in a list on a specific index with no imperative thingys

Tags: list, ocaml

I need to alter an element of a list on a specific index, but I can't use or simulate any imperative coding. I had this code:

```
let rec addl c l index=
match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> 
        if c.number = index
            then (x + 1)::xs
        else x::addl c xs (index + 1)
;;
```

but I'm not allowed to use arguments with a variable that changes over time, I see no other way of doing this without that variable

Comment: This code doesn't use any imperative thingys. :-) Replacing mutable variables by immutable function parameters is the essence of functional coding.

Comment: hm i thougth that too, but i´ll translate what has been said to me "is that function using an argument to simulate a variable which is being altered over time?" and isnt it whats happening here?... also i think this restrictions are retarded but in the end its him who grades the tests

Comment: There's no mutation in this code. Any recursive code is going to have parameters that have different values different times. Same if you use a fold. I don't get the point, but maybe there is one.

Comment: @AMNevess what has been said to you is unprecise wording. Of course we have to use function parameters to hold new/calculated values, the point is you should never assign a different value to an existing binding (mutation).

Comment: @Str. I get it now, but what they tell us is kinda unprecise as you said, i spoke with my teacher and he says that method is right if i work in intervals, i had to add a [0,9] interval i pass on the arguments, instead of a for simulation i kinda understand it as if someone passed 10 (which it can't but imagine they will) it would not stop, with intervals it works and he said it is more human logic and thats what they are teaching us, letting go machine logic aka imperative, on this semester

Comment: Do you remember what the "right" answere to the question was? Because the way you asked it your code is exactly the correct answere and I can't see any fudamentally different way to do what you asked with a list.